# bash while loop through a file doesn't end when the file is deleted

Tags: bash, while-loop, diskcache

I have a while loop in a bash script:

Example:

```
while read LINE
do
echo $LINE >> $log_file
done < ./sample_file
```

My question is why when I delete the sample_file while the script is running the loop doesn't end and I see that the log_file is updating? How the loop is continuing while there is no input?

Answer (score 2):

In unix, a file isn't truly deleted until the last directory entry for it is removed (e.g. with `rm`) *and* the last open file handle for it is closed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handler-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-de) (especially MarkR's answer) for more info. In the case of your script, the file is opened as stdin for the `while read` loop, and until that loop exits (or closes its stdin), `rm`ing the file will not actually delete it off disk.

You can see this effect pretty easily if you want. Open three terminal windows. In the first, run the command `cat >/tmp/deleteme`. In the second, run `tail -f /tmp/deleteme`. In the third, after running the other two commands, run `rm /tmp/deleteme`. At this point, the file has been unlinked, but both the `cat` and `tail` processes have open file handles for it, so it hasn't actually been deleted. You can prove this by typing into the first terminal window (running `cat`), and every time your hit return, `tail` will see the new line added to the file and display it in the second window.

The file will not actually be deleted until you end those two commands (Control-D will end `cat`, but you need Control-C to kill `tail`).

Answer (score 2):

See ["Why file is accessible after deleting in unix?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22252641/8793989) for an excellent explanation of what you are observing here.

In short...

> Underlying rm and any other command that may appear to delete a file
>   there is the system call unlink. And it's called unlink, not remove or
>   deletefile or anything similar, because it doesn't remove a file. It
>   removes a link (a.k.a. directory entry) which is an association
>   between a file and a name in a directory.

You can use the function `truncate` to destroy the actual contents (or `shred` if you need to be more secure), which would immediately halt the execution of your example loop.

Answer (score 0):

The moment shell executes the while loop, the `sample_file` contents have been read, and it does not matter whether the file exists or not after that point.

Test script:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo $line
    sleep 1
done < data_file
```

Test file:

```
$ seq 1 10 > data_file
```

Now, in one terminal you run the script, in another terminal, you go and delete the file `data_file`, you would still see the 1 to 10 numbers printed by the script.